# How to show only one error message from Laravel request rules

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I am using Laravel request to validate in my controller the requested data

[image: controllerstrong text]

and here is my request file data

[image]

**I am facing two challanges**

1. first I am not able to return custom message using **static** function
2. I am not able to send single message as we send in controller validation using errors()->first().

By defalut it is returning like that

[image]

but I want like below SS

[image]
**Is there I can send first message using request ?**

Comment: what's laravel version you're using?

Comment: build yourself a custom validator

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/984422) when asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-To custom message

```
 Laravel Documents customizing-the-error-messages
```

-To return a single error message

```
    //In Request
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
    
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' =>$validator->errors()->first(),
            'data' => null,
        ], 422));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using laravel 8 or 9 you can do that using the attribute `$stopOnFirstFailure` of your FormRequest Class

```
class UpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether validation should stop after the first rule failure.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $stopOnFirstFailure = false;

    //...
}
```

as for the response rendering, you need to add a custom render/format in your exception handler (App/Exceptions/Handler.php) to catch the validation exception thrown and return the json format you need.